# Getting value of a textbox and transfer to controller(Codeigniter)PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem when i transfer value from view to controller. I don't get the value
Here's my method

Manifest.php

```
<?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) {  ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="voyage_id" value="<?=$voyage->voyage_id?>">
  <a class="btn btn-primary primary-bg btn-lg  col-md-2 m-3 btn-cus" href="<?php  echo base_url('PortClient/view_voyage/');?>">
  <h3>Voyage - <?=$voyage->voyage_number?></h3> 
  <small>Schedule - <?=$voyage->expected_arrival?> </small>
  </a>
<?php }  ?>
```

I want to get the value of voyage_id(Code above) in manifest.php(view page) and transfer it to controller.
Here's my controller

PortClient.php

```
public function view_voyage() {
    $this->Auth->authCheck();
    $data = $this->template();
    $voyage_id = $this->session->userdata('voyage_id');

    $data['view_cargo'] = $this->PortManifestModel->view_voyage($voyage_id)->result();
    // your code here
    $this->load->view("port/client/sub_manifest/sub_manifest_1", $data);
}
```

and i will call it using $this->session->userdata() but it doesnt transfer.

What should I do?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. The HTML is creating an input field with some value and then a normal link. How are you sending that input filed? Using javascript? Also, in your PostClient-file, you're only trying to fetch the `$voyage_id` from the session. Where did you set that session? Sessions and form data are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a form and access the value on form submit. OR you can use AJAX to post the value and access it like: `$this->input->post("voyage_id")` instead of using the session

Comment: Hello. Here's what I did. <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('PortClient/view_voyage/');?>"> <div class=" container"> <div class="row"><?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) { ?> <input type="hidden" name="voyage_id" value="<?=$voyage->voyage_id?>"> </form> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary-bg btn-lg col-md-2 m-3 btn-cus"> <h3>Voyage - <?=$voyage->voyage_number?></h3> <small>Schedule - <?=$voyage->expected_arrival?> </small> </button> <? </div>

Comment: Your button is outside the </form> tag. Please include it inside the form to allow submitting it

Comment: Still not working mate. My query in model Still not working mate :(. My query in model public function view_voyage($voyage_id){
 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM port_voyage_cargo WHERE voyage_id = ?";

  $data = array($voyage_id);

  return $this->db->query($sql,$data);
  
 }

Comment: Can you check the value of $this->input->post('voyage_id'); in view_voyage() and also display the last query in model

Answer (score 0):

You are using session to get the value.Rather you must use POST Or GET method after form is submitted (use form either) -

`$voyage_id = $this->session->userdata('voyage_id');`

Here above this is wrong.Submit the form/use ajax and get the value using -

`$voyage_id = $this->input->post('voyage_id');`

OR

Other Option is-
if you are storing `voyage_id` in one function and also sending same value to the form then you do not need to set it in the hidden element (make sure that this is the exact `voyage_id` you need after form submission) then remove html element and you can achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello. Here's what I did. <form method="POST" action="<?php  echo base_url('PortClient/view_voyage/');?>">
                      
                               
                                       <div class=" container">
 <div class="row"><?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) {  ?>

<input type="hidden" name="voyage_id" value="<?=$voyage->voyage_id?>">
</form>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary-bg btn-lg  col-md-2 m-3 btn-cus">
<h3>Voyage - <?=$voyage->voyage_number?></h3> 
<small>Schedule - <?=$voyage->expected_arrival?> </small>
 </button>
<? </div>

Comment: you have added submit button outside form tag. please add that inside form tag

Comment: Still not working mate :(. My query in model public function view_voyage($voyage_id){
 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM port_voyage_cargo WHERE voyage_id = ?";

  $data = array($voyage_id);

  return $this->db->query($sql,$data);
  
 }

Comment: see, you do not have to focus first on model. check in controller if $voyage_id is having proper value OR not. If it will never be available at model.Focus on capturing value in value in controller and then pass it to model.