# Getting value of a textbox using form(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem getting the value of textbox and transfer it to controller

here's my code

manifest.php(view)

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php  echo base_url('PortClient/view_voyage/');?>">  
      <div class=" container">                         
      <div class="row">
      <?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) {  ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="voyage_id" value="<?=$voyage->voyage_id?>">
 </form>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary-bg btn-lg  col-md-2 m-3 btn-cus">
          <h3>Voyage - <?=$voyage->voyage_number?></h3> 
          <small>Schedule - <?=$voyage->expected_arrival?> </small>
      </button>

<?php }  ?>
```

I want to get voyage_id and transfer it to controller

PortClient.php (controller)

```
public function view_voyage() {
    $this->Auth->authCheck();
    $data = $this->template();
    $voyage_id = $this->input->post('voyage_id');

    $data['view_cargo'] = $this->PortManifestModel->view_voyage($voyage_id)->result();
    // your code here
    $this->load->view("port/client/sub_manifest/sub_manifest_1", $data);
}
```

The value of voyage_id textbox doesnt transfer

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value of a textbox and transfer to controller(Codeigniter)PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960494/getting-value-of-a-textbox-and-transfer-to-controllercodeigniterphp)

Comment: Does `$voyage_info` only ever have a single entry in the array, if not then check to see if you have multiple hidden inputs with the same name.

Comment: What you getting output of `var_dump($voyage_info)` in the view ?

Comment: first correct your html generated by foreach statement

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add name in your button.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit button</button>
```

modify your controller

```
public function view_voyage() {
    $this->Auth->authCheck();
    $data = $this->template();

    if($_POST["submit"]){
        $voyage_id = $this->input->post('voyage_id');

        $data['view_cargo'] = $this->PortManifestModel->view_voyage($voyage_id)->result();
    }
    $this->load->view("port/client/sub_manifest/sub_manifest_1", $data);
}
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

Please add your submit button within form.

Currently Button is placed after form, you should add it into form.

And also you have correct for loop.